# Java StringBuilder append long String error

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I tried to append a long String (length of 3000) with java StringBuilder and found out that the appended result is not what I expected.

`A.append(B)` should be `AB`

`A.append(LongString)` becomes `A________________(empty spaces)`

Any idea?

My code: http://pastebin.com/5CPmHFeS

Comment: I tried your code, it works as expected.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using. It worked fine for me on Java 6 update 26.

Comment: It works just fine, tested with Ideone: http://ideone.com/zgzi0

Comment: seems like a bug in the Eclipse console that display 404040 as space. They look fine if I copy and paste into notepad. Interesting.

Comment: Eclipse has a few bug with rendering **very** long lines (well past 1000 characters, at least). They can lead to ugly rendering errors or (as in your case) simply to empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

What did you get as output? I got:

```
sb-320 :404040....
sb-4320:404040....
```

Truncated for readability, but its correct. I think you may have counted the digits incorrectly. Double check?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any problem, that I see.

It works properly : http://www.ideone.com/z8Lxu